# Why the icon doesn't display when I build the app but displays on npm start?

Tags: electron, icons, png

Electron app.

The code below converts the .icns file to the .png and DOM displays it.
It works when `npm start` but when I build the app  (`yarn app:dir`), the image doesn't display.

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'icon_128x128.png')
```

[console.log(iconsPng)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehza0.png)

Code:

```
  // Convert an ICNS file to an Iconset
  const iconutil = require('iconutil');

  iconutil.toIconset(localIconPath, function(err, iconsPng) {
  const iconsBuffer = iconsPng['icon_128x128.png'];
  console.log(iconsPng);

  // Convert iconsBuffer to an Uint8Array
  const nativeImage = require('electron').nativeImage
  const image = nativeImage.createFromBuffer(iconsBuffer)
  const uint8 = image.toPNG()

  // Uint8Array to DOM
  const blob = new Blob([uint8], {
    'type': 'image/png'
  });
  const urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  const imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
  const img = document.querySelector("#localIcon");
  img.src = imageUrl;
```

package.json:

```
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dev": "concurrently -k \"BROWSER=none npm start\" \"npm:electron\"",
    "electron": "wait-on tcp:3000 && electron .",
    "app:dir": "electron-builder --dir",
    "app:dist": "electron-builder",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
```